# How can I convert a String into a Boolean expression

Tags: java

I have a String (let's say) comp = "3 == 5";

How can I convert that `String` into a `boolean` expression that can be evaluated to `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do it. That's what compilers do. You have to parse the String, identify the type of each token (in your example, two int constants and one equality operator) and evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 0):

[Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

That post concerns mathematical expression, but after testing it, I realized it also applies to boolean expression as well.